# Give an example of a quotient ring R/I such that R/I have unity but R does not have unity.

Tags: ring-theory

In a book we are given that $R=$ ring of matrices of the type $$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$and $I$ of the type$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&x\\0&0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$
over the integers. I am not able to find the identity of $R/I$. I tried using the definition but I failed. Can someone tell me about the identity of $R/I$ and that $R$ has no identity. Also it is given that $R/I$ is commutative but $R$ is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that $R$ has no (multiplicative) identity, let's first take a look at how multiplication works in $R$:$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ac&ad\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Now, suppose $R$ has an identity element. Recall that an identity must be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Idempotent_elements_and_binary_operations). Determine the form of an $x$ satisfying this property and prove that nothing of this form can be the identity--for this, consider $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: is an multiplicative identity is also idempotent? why you have written additive identity ??I was asking for multiplicative identity.

Comment: @abc I meant *multiplicative* identity. Thanks. $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is the additive identity of course.

Answer (score 1):

$R/I$ can be seen as matrices of the type $$\begin{pmatrix}
a&*\\0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $*$ means "don't care". Multiplication in this ring is by $$\begin{pmatrix}
a&*\\0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
b&*\\0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ab&*\\0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ where I've just totally ignored whatever is going on in the $*$ squares. So it's clear that $R/I\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the identity is $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&*\\0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: how i show that R has no unity

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\mapsto a$ is a ring homomorphism(!) $R\to \mathbb Z$ with $I$ as kernel.

Comment: then?? please expand a little bit i can't understand.

Comment: Then $R/I\cong \mathbb Z$ (as the homomorphism is onto)

Comment: thanks. Is then as $\mathbbZ$ is commutative then R/I is commutative?? please also tell me how can I show that R has no unity??