# About rings $R$ without multiplicative identity such that $R/I$ has unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I want to study about rings lacking unity but having a nontrivial proper ideal $I$ such that $R/I$ has unity.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/501160/762081) talks about one of such rings which is a non-abliean infinite ring.

Is it possible to find such rings if we restrict ourselves to

- finite abelian rings ?
- infinite abelian rings ?
- finite non-abelian rings ?

I tried but can't really come up with examples. Any help is highly appreciated.

Also, as a bonus question, what restriction on $R$ shall force $R$ to have a unity if $R/I$ has a unity ?

Comment: If you take $I = R$, then $R/I$ is the [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring), which has unity.

Comment: Oh yes ! You are right. But it would clearly be more interesting to consider nontrivial proper ideals. I have edited my question to fill this loophole. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The word "abelian" is not used to refer to commutative rings. You should say "commutative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A$ a ring with unit, and $B$ a ring without unit, and define $R=A\times B$ and $I=\{0\}\times B$. Then $R$ is a ring without unit, and $I\subset R$ is an ideal such that $R/I\simeq A$ has a unit.

Now you can choose $A$ and $B$ as you like, so if they are both commutative then $R$ is commutative, and if they are both finite $R$ is finite (and $R$ is infinite when one of them is).

Comment: Clever ! Thank you.